# Patterns for Sidelining in streaming application

Tags: apache-flink, spark-streaming, apache-storm

I have a spark streaming application. It takes a batch of records and executes multiple map functions over records.

When few records fail in .map stage, I want to be able to know the original id/record that has failed so that I can put it in sideline and retry later. Can someone please suggest patterns around this? putting try catch on every .map function does not sound feasible (if this is the only way, should i try to reduce the .map functions. )

Since other streaming frameworks like storm and flink work on record level, will it be easier to implement sidelining there?

Answer (score 0):

With Flink you would use a ProcessFunction rather than a map, and wrap the transformation that might fail in a try catch. Records that cause an exception are then sent to a side output.

It's going to look something like this:

```java
        final OutputTag<String> errors = new OutputTag<>("errors") {};

        final SingleOutputStreamOperator<Event> transformedStream =
                env.fromSource(source, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "Source")
                        .process(
                                new ProcessFunction<>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void processElement(
                                            String value,
                                            ProcessFunction<String, Event>.Context ctx,
                                            Collector<Event> out) {
                                        final Event transformed;
                                        try {
                                            transformed = myTransformation(value);
                                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                            ctx.output(errors, value);
                                            return;
                                        }
                                        out.collect(transformed);
                                    }
                                });
```